# Failed to setup IP tables: Unable to enable NAT rule

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am doing this tutorial: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools

Now i want to start the hyperledger fabric with `./startFabric.sh` but then I get this error:

```
dany@DESKTOP-IQB2P0B:~/fabric-dev-servers$ ./startFabric.sh
Development only script for Hyperledger Fabric control
Running 'startFabric.sh'
FABRIC_VERSION is set to 'hlfv12'
FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT is unset, assuming 15 (seconds)
Removing network composer_default
WARNING: Network composer_default not found.
Creating network "composer_default" with the default driver
ERROR: Failed to Setup IP tables: Unable to enable NAT rule:  (iptables failed: iptables --wait -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 172.22.0.0/16 ! -o br-b49f324730b7 -j MASQUERADE: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
 (exit status 1))
```

Before I had this error: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4181

But I fixed it and now I have this error...

Comment: can you try running on your linux system: iptables -L POSTROUTING ?

Comment: I got this output: `iptables v1.6.1: can't initialize iptables table filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.`

Comment: how about just: ` iptables -L`

Answer (score 14):

Try:

```sh
sudo iptables -t filter -N DOCKER
```

```sh
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Check this:

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/16816#issuecomment-179717327

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Debian-based distribution, then the problem could be in `nftables`: https://forums.docker.com/t/failing-to-start-dockerd-failed-to-create-nat-chain-docker/78269/2

> The docker installer uses iptables for NAT. Unfortunately Debian uses nftables. You can convert the entries over to nftables or just setup Debian to use the legacy iptables.

```bash
sudo update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy
sudo update-alternatives --set ip6tables /usr/sbin/ip6tables-legacy
sudo systemctl restart docker
```