Docker.service Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE (OS: ubuntu 22.04)
sudo systemctl status docker
× docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2024-05-06 18:25:25 UTC; 6min ago
TriggeredBy: × docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
    Process: 1632897 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1632897 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 06 18:25:22 server systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 06 18:25:22 server systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 06 18:25:22 server systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
May 06 18:25:25 server systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
May 06 18:25:25 server systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
May 06 18:25:25 server systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 06 18:25:25 server systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 06 18:25:25 server systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.

May 06 18:25:22 server systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit docker.service has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit docker.service has begun execution.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 3281362.
May 06 18:25:22 server dockerd[1632897]: time="2024-05-06T18:25:22.186308133Z" level=info msg="Starting up"
May 06 18:25:22 server dockerd[1632897]: time="2024-05-06T18:25:22.190370332Z" level=info msg="detected 127.0.0.53 nameserver, assuming systemd-resolved, so using resolv.conf: /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf"
May 06 18:25:22 server dockerd[1632897]: time="2024-05-06T18:25:22.292233833Z" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2"
May 06 18:25:22 server dockerd[1632897]: time="2024-05-06T18:25:22.292729359Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
May 06 18:25:22 server dockerd[1632897]: time="2024-05-06T18:25:22.884221906Z" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
May 06 18:25:22 server dockerd[1632897]: failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: error creating default "bridge" network: Failed to Setup IP tables: Unable to enable NAT rule:  (iptables failed: iptables --wait -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUER>
May 06 18:25:22 server dockerd[1632897]:  (exit status 4))
May 06 18:25:22 server systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit docker.service has exited.
░░
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
May 06 18:25:22 server systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

I am not the one to give up quickly, but man oh man, WHAT IS GOING ON? I have managed to pinpoint the problem down to something to do with the iptables but after completely fucking up my firewall I still dont know what is going on. I flushed iptables and tried restarting docker - didn't help. I then reinstalled ip tables and tried again- didnt help. I tried looking on the web couldn't find anything to solve the problem, even tried the GPT Could anyone provide some assistance on this?
Also tried this: systemctl start docker - Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code
sudo iptables --wait -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUER
iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables): Chain 'MASQUER' does not exist
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information

Could it be that the OVPN server that I am running?

Solved:https://stackoverflow.com/a/76215040/21229427

Solution:
All credit goes to this genius man https://stackoverflow.com/a/76215040/21229427

The docker installer uses iptables for NAT. Unfortunately Debian uses nftables. You can convert the entries over to nftables or just setup Debian to use the legacy iptables.

sudo update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy
sudo update-alternatives --set ip6tables /usr/sbin/ip6tables-legacy
sudo systemctl restart docker

So the problem was with iptables and debian distros using iptables-legacy as well. So you need to update legacy for docker to start. No joke this took a good 4 hrs)
